# Excel VBA to delete column with first cell starting with '

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere and am still new to VBA. I have a program that exports data to excel. I need VBA code to delete specific columns with headers equal to strings. I am having issues because one column is exported with ' preceding the word. Here is my code:

```
For i = 1 To 7
If Cells(1, i).Value = "A" Then
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = "'B" Then
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = "C" Then
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
End If
Next i
```

The issue is the "B" column. I've tried = "B" and = "'B" and neither work. Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if I'm not being clear.

I've also tried:

```
ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = Chr(39) & "B" Then
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: Does you column header really starts with '? Isn't it something similar like ´? Try to copy the header value directly into your VBA code.

Comment: Yes, it does. I did try copying directly and it still does not work.

Comment: I've tried "B", "'B", "´B", Chr(34) & "B", Chr(96) & "B" and nothing is deleting that column. Unfortunately, the column will be in different positions so I can't just refer to a column number

Comment: I can't seem to replicate.  I put `'B` in C1 and ran your code with `ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = "B" Then` and it worked.  Are you sure there are no other characters in the cell like spaces or other non printable characters.  The `'` in the first forces excel to read it as a literal string.

Comment: Ok. I don't have Excel here so I can't test it. If you add ´msgbox Cells(1, i).Value´ to your loop, what does it says about that column? Or you should be able to use InStr or Right function, but I know, that would not be a nice solution.

Comment: @ScottCraner Not that I can see in Excel. I tried replicating it and adding ' for other columns manually but it still deletes it with my code. I'm stuck.

Comment: Try this,  manualy find the address of the cell in which the problem is found.  Then put this in the immediate window `? "'" & Range("C1").value & "'"` where C1 is the address of the cell that is being skipped.  and hit enter.  It should return `'B'`  If it does not you have your answer.

Comment: @velblúd your ´msgbox Cells(1, i).Value´ suggestion made me realize it was skipping. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix here... Not sure why I didn't think of this. Since I was deleting a column before "B", it was skipping right over it. Solution is to reverse. Thanks for all the help everyone!

```
For i = 7 To 1 Step -1
If Cells(1, i).Value = "A" Then
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = "B" Then
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = "C" Then
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Sometimes its the easy ones we all miss.